# Why do we need to select a board to work with arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

I always wondered how this works . In arduino IDE we have option to select different boards because the code upload i guess is different ? Also there is possibility to even add board manager url to add other boards.

Why uploading the code is so different from board to board , and what exactly differs there ? The code is sent to via serial connection and i understand that a board might have different chip for handling USB to serial but ..

Can someone explain as clear as possible , how the code is uploaded to a board and why there is no generic way , why so many configurations.

Thanks and sorry if is a dumb question.

Comment: "*why there is no generic way*" Different manufacturers, different needs, different technology, different designs, different available interfaces, ... The question is way too broad.

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: The most important change is the CPU architecture targeted by the compiler and libraries and not the uploading.

Answer (score 2):

One of the important things that selecting a board does is, as you say, inform the IDE of how to load code onto the board. Perhaps more importantly, the board definitions give you the logical mapping of the board's hardware to the code constructs you are using to program against. For example, have you ever wondered what happens when you use a constant like `PIN_13`, or how that constant maps to a physical pin on your board, which has a trace to some contact on the microcontroller chip itself?

There is a lot of *other* code you don't see, much of it in the board definitions (and some in the Arduino core) which lets you work with relatively direct concepts (like pin numbers and modes) in the code that you write or edit.